# Maven Build specific childs from Parent

Tags: maven

Can we build specific child from a parent Pom in Maven.May be using a file that mentions the name of the modules to be included.

Answer (score 4):

If you in root location of your project you can simply define that on command line of Maven like this:

```
mvn -pl ModuleYouWouldLikeToBuild package
```

Excerpt from the command line help:

```
 -pl,--projects <arg>                   Comma-delimited list of specified
                                        reactor projects to build instead
                                        of all projects. A project can be
                                        specified by [groupId]:artifactId
                                        or by its relative path.
```

If this module what you like to build is used by an other module you can decide to let maven analyze which one and build that depending module also by using:

```
mvn -pl Module  --also-make-dependents
```

or short version:

```
mvn -pl Module -amd
```

If you have modules which are used by the module you triggered to build you can also add:

```
mvn -pl Module --also-make
```

or short version:

```
mvn -pl Module -am
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume your root project has 3 modules: `module-A`, `module-B` and `module-C`.

Run the commands below from your root project.

- If you want to build `module-C`, run: `mvn clean install –pl module-C`
- In case `module-C` depends on `module-A`, run:
  `mvn clean install –pl module-C –am` to build `module-A` and `module-C`

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven profile to achieve this.

```
<project>
...
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>build1</id>
            <activation>
                <property>build1</property>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>module1</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>build2</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>test2.file</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <modules>
                <module>module2</module>
                <module>module3</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

You can activate profile by some conditions, eg. present or missing files, existing properties and so on.

More info about maven profile:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: Never use profiles for including/excluding modules better use the command --projects for such things.